# Implicit conversion error C# netstandard2.1

Tags: c#, h3

I'm trying to port [some code](https://github.com/pocketken/H3.net/tree/main/src/H3) from Net5.0 to Netstandard2.1, but running out of C# knowledge.

I am trying to rewrite this function

```
public static readonly Dictionary<Direction, CoordIJK> DirectionToUnitVector =
    Enum.GetValues<Direction>().ToDictionary(e => e, e => e switch {
        Direction.Invalid => CoordIJK.InvalidIJKCoordinate,
        _ => UnitVectors[(int)e]
    });
```

My attempt so far is:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<Direction, CoordIJK> DirectionToUnitVector =
    (Direction[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).ToString().ToDictionary(e => e, e => e switch {   
        Direction.Invalid => CoordIJK.InvalidIJKCoordinate, 
        _ => UnitVectors[(int)e]
    });
```

which is giving me

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'H3.Model.Direction' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

For reference, `Direction` is defined as the following `Enum`

```
public enum Direction
{
    Center = 0,
    K = 1,
    J = 2,
    JK = 3,
    I = 4,
    IK = 5,
    IJ = 6,
    Invalid = 7
}
```

and `CoordIJK.InvalidIJKCoordinate` is defined as

```
public static readonly CoordIJK InvalidIJKCoordinate = new CoordIJK(-int.MaxValue, -int.MaxValue, -int.MaxValue);

public CoordIJK(int i, int j, int k) {
    I = i;
    J = j;
    K = k;
}
```

Firstly, everything after the `DirectionToUnitVector` is pretty much just magic symbols to me. How is the garble of code going to return a `Dictionary<Direction, CoordIJK>` and what can I do to fix it? I naively tried just adding `(char)` before `Direction.Invalid` to fix the error, but that didn't solve the issue.

Any help would be great.

Edit001: Added in the original code.

Comment: `(Direction[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).ToString()` Did you add that `ToString` there, or was it in the original?

Comment: I added that in, and the `Direction[]` at the start, cause that's what my googling discovered was a potential fix for another issue. I'll fix the question to have the original code.

Comment: Yeah, that `ToString` should clearly not be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you can't use `switch` that way in .Net Standard

try this

```
using System.Linq;

public static readonly Dictionary<Direction, CoordIJK> DirectionToUnitVector =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>().ToDictionary(e => e, e => {
   return e == Direction.Invalid ? CoordIJK.InvalidIJKCoordinate : UnitVectors[(int)e];
});
```

If you add `using System.Linq;` and still having issues with missing `ToDictionary()` try rewriting it like so:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<Direction, CoordIJK> DirectionToUnitVector =
    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>(), e => e, e => {
   return e == Direction.Invalid ? CoordIJK.InvalidIJKCoordinate : UnitVectors[(int)e];
});
```

Comment: That fixes *that* error, but another has popped up about the `ToDictionary`
```
Error CS1061 'Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and no accessible extension method 'ToDictionary' accepting a first argument of type 'Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: @infinityplusb You likely removed some of the `using`s at the top of https://github.com/pocketken/H3.net/blob/0264123d4050ee8a671685631f2a363fff9f2520/src/H3/Model/LookupTables.cs from the file.

Comment: No, those 4 are still there. 
I'm trying to change as little as possible, so really just fixing the errors. Is `Array.ToDictionary()` a thing in net5 that isn't in .net standard?

Comment: Unless there is another using that is implied in net5, that I can include?

Comment: @infinityplusb there is no `Array.ToDictionary()`, only `Enumerable.ToDictionary()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0

Comment: @zaitsman cool beans. `System.Linq` was already included, but your new version of the function compiled.